# Float operations

Tags: c++, operators

my question is related to the correct assignment of variables. My first question is about float division and if this two ways of doing it are the same in functionality and compiled code and if there is any advantage using one form or other:

All the variables are floats.

```
m_top = m_near * tanf(m_fovy/2.0f);
```

or

```
m_top = m_near * tanf(m_fovy/2);
```

My second question is the same but with the assignment of a negative variable

```
m_bottom = -1.0f * m_top;
```

or

```
m_bottom = -m_top;
```

Comment: Write your code in the clearest way possible and let the compiler worry about optimisations

Comment: In my experience, multiplying by 0.5 is faster than dividing by 2.

Comment: Depending on what the mysterious `m_fovy` object is, actually, dividing it by `2` versus `2.0` will produce different results.

Comment: Agreed, you can put your code into godbolt.org and then look at the generated assembly. It will be the same. The compiler is a good boi and will make it as optimized as possible

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it's a float as stated in the question

Comment: Checkout https://godbolt.org/ and write a couple of lines. Change the optimization level between -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3. You will notice that for your comparisons -O0 doesn't differentiate between one or another form. Once you enable optimizations, the compiler doesn't care about what you wrote. What's real is that multiplying by 0.5 is much better than doing divisions.

Comment: @JorgeLópez Thank you so much, I will use this page when I need to check this things

Comment: Read about "As-if rule" and stop worrying about such unimportant details.

Comment: *... is any advantage using one form or other?*  **Yes**, the one that is more legible, straightforward, and clearer definitely has advantage.

Comment: @zpip101 [As-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). The program that you write is only a description of what you want done.  All of the operations you listed *describe* the behavior you want.  Just because you place a `-` sign instead of `-1.0f` will make no difference to the compiler that is looking at your code.  The compiler will detect it is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter, the compiler optimizes the code anyway